# Why doesn't setMask work is this example after it worked once

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I'm trying to use setMask to create 3 "windows" of masked movieClips in AS2 (CS3).

The main window is masked fine.

After clicking a button, I'm creating two additional windows, but the refuse to be masked No error, it's just that the mask is not applied, and the mask rectangle is still visible.

All 3 windows are masked using the same function, with different MC parameter.

I have nested MCs, but basically, the main window is masked as:

```
_level0.GUI.OBJ.mainWinMC.mainWindowMC.mainWindow.setMask(_level0.GUI.OBJ.mainWinMC.mainWindowMC.mainWindow_PlanMask);
```

where `mainWindow_PlanMask` contains an MC with a red rectangle. (Note: I'm using MovieClip variables and I posted here their movieclip traced path.
This works fine.

After pressing a button, I'm setting two more masks:

```
_level0.GUI.OBJ.mainWinMC.side0MC.side0.setMask(_level0.GUI.OBJ.mainWinMC.side0MC.side0_PlanMask);

_level0.GUI.OBJ.mainWinMC.side1MC.side1.setMask(_level0.GUI.OBJ.mainWinMC.side1MC.side1_PlanMask);
```

`side0_PlanMask and side1_PlanMask` contain rectangles too.
But in these cases, the red rectangle is kept visible and the mask is not applied.
I have no idea why. Any help will be appreciated.

[Edit]
applying cacheAsBitmap all MCs from both mask and masked MCs to the _root caused the first mask operation not to work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Masks in Flash can be unpredictable. Try setting cacheAsBitmap to true for everything.

UPDATE:

Try setting cacheAsBitmap to true for each movieclip going down from the _root. Try Embedding all fonts on any textfields that are inside the movieclip you are masking - infact make sure you have embedded all your fonts everywhere.

Comment: I've set cacheAsBitmap to true on the MC and the mask MC, before the setMask and after the setMask.
Didn't work.
It was a good idea, though. I'm looking for such insights since I already tried so many changes... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to help you debug with the provided information

you can try:

1. make sure you have correctly named the movieclips with an incorrect instance names (sometimes you will find that you forgot to name some of the movieclips)
2. open a new fla and make a much more simple version of the things that you want to do, so that you can isolate the errors.

btw, not really necessary, but try using _root instead of _level0, it will be clearer.

Comment: I'm not using _level0 nor _root. I'm using MovieClip variables, I just posted their paths here (as displayed by a trace command).

1. All the MCs are created dynamically in AS, so I can't really forget to name any.

2. The first example IS working, and I'm using the same function.